# Dynamic User Query Params in Mongoose $all Query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schemas which represent a product specifications,

```
const MoldSpecific = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      en: String,
      ar: String,
      kr: String,
    },
    values: [MoldValue.schema],
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
  }
);

export default model("MoldSpecific", MoldSpecific);

const MoldValue = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      en: String,
      ar: String,
      kr: String,
    },
    unit: { type: String, default: "" },
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
  }
);

export default model("MoldValue", MoldValue);
```

The user can pick any specifics like color or manufacture year, size, ... etc, So I'm using below code to add each query param (if exists) to `specParams` array and then try to `map` or `join` the array elements in my query but its always fail,

```
export function getQueryParams(query) {
var queryParams = {};
  var specsParams = [];
  if (query.year) {
    specsParams.push({ $elemMatch: { "values._id": query.year } });
  }
  if (query.color) {
    specsParams.push({ $elemMatch: { "values._id": query.color } });
  }
  queryParams["specifics"] = {
    $all: [specsParams.join()],
  };
  console.log(queryParams);
  return queryParams;
}
```

I used both `map` and `join` with the `specParams` array but it always gave error :

```
ObjectParameterError: Parameter \"obj\" to Document() must be an object, got [object Object],[object Object]"
```

note :  this code is working

```
queryParams["specifics"] = {
    $all: [specsParams[0]],
  };
```

Any ideas or help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to join, simply passing the array should suffice:

```
queryParams["specifics"] = {
    $all: specsParams,
 };
```